SHAP Waterfall diagram as a matplotlib subplot?
Hi i would like to Show side by side diagrams from SHAP Library:

Waterfall Diagram :API Reference https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.plots.waterfall.html#shap.plots.waterfall

Bar plot : API reference https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.plots.bar.html


i am using standard Matplotlib line
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
whole code is as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def shap_diagrams(shapley_values, index=0):
    fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
    ax0 = shap.plots.waterfall(shapley_values[index], show= False)
    ax0.set_title('SHAP Waterfall Plot')
    plt.gca()
    shap.plots.bar(shapley_values,ax=ax1, show= False)
    ax1.set_title('SHAP Bar Plot')
    
    plt.show()

and after calling a function shap_diagrams(shap_values,2)diagrams are overlayed. Please advise.
i have tried different assignments but where supposed to be waterfall "axes"the is an empty ax object,and waterfall diagram itself jump over to properly rendered barplotenter image description here

It looks like shap’s waterfall function is using pyplot to do everything on the current axes.  You could try setting the current axes before the waterfall call with plt.sca(ax0).

That's because you're appending axes to the ones of subplots, leading to a total of four:
[
    <Axes: >,
    <Axes: title={'center': 'SHAP Bar Plot'}, xlabel='mean(|SHAP value|)'>,
    <Axes: >,
    <Axes: title={'center': 'SHAP Waterfall Plot'}>
]

And since the waterfall doesn't have an ax parameter, you need to sca before calling it :
def shap_diagrams(shapley_values, index=0):
    fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    plt.sca(ax0)

    shap.plots.waterfall(shapley_values[index], show=False)
    ax0.set_title("SHAP Waterfall Plot")

    shap.plots.bar(shapley_values, ax=ax1, show=False)
    ax1.set_title("SHAP Bar Plot", pad=25)

    # to horizontally separate the two axes
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=1)
    # because waterfall seems to update the figsize
    fig.set_size_inches(10, 3)

    plt.show()

shap_diagrams(shap_values, 2)


Used input :
import xgboost
import shap

X, y = shap.datasets.adult(n_points=2000)
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier().fit(X, y)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model, X)
shap_values = explainer(X)


Thanks. i Tried sca() after a walk and it indeed worked fine.  Its True That waterfall changes the size so your fig.set_size_inches(10, 3) on very end its a good catch. i just wonder why they didnt include Ax argument in the first place. Thanks For your suuport . Considered Solved
